# Como descargar el excel generado con PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Tengo un archivo excel generado en PHP con PhpSpreadsheet.

Cómo funciona: mediante un boton por ajax envío un id y genero un excel con PhpSpreadshee, eso funciona pero lo guarda en el mismo directorio y lo que quiero es que el navegador lo descargue. Estoy intentando con esto:

Pero no funciona no descarga.....cómo logro hacer esto

```html
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Style;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'El ID del USUARIO ES:'.$usuario);



$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xlsx"');
    $writer->save("php://output");

?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué comportamiento tiene el código actualmente? ¿Da algún error o algo? Intenta poner `exit();` al final.  Y si no funciona, prueba a ponerlo así: `ob_end_clean(); $writer->save("php://output"); exit();`

Comment: Lo solucione, lo solicite con un <a> y listo, en el href envie por get el id...